# Setting ERC-20 token price

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm currently trying to set the token price of my ERC-20 token.The problem I'm having is trying to set the price to ETH(0.01) per token, but the closest value I keep getting to is ETH(0.001) per token when making a transaction to buy.

```
// Denominations example   
// ether = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000
var tokenPrice = 1000000000000; 
deployer.deploy(DappTokenSale, DappToken.address, tokenPrice);
```

I've tried passing in  different values with no effect in getting ETH(0.01), and well tried just setting the value in the contract without passing in this large number.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I had to do a complete reset of Metamask accounts and blockchain server, values are working as expected now.